# Does C have a 64k limit on declared variable size?

Tags: c++, c++builder

First let me explain that I am a circuit designer, not a software engineer, so maybe this question falls into the "Well Duhhh" category.

I have problems when I declare a variable where the array requires more than 64k of memory. e.g.

```
char MyVar[100000];
```

The compiler doesn't give any error messages or warnings, but the code has obvious memory problems. i.e. Weird execution that can't be tracked in the debugger.

I knew there were memory limitations 20 years ago, but I thought Windows solved those problems.

I realize the solution is to use the new operator, but I am puzzled that I can't find any documentation on this.

Does C have a 64k limit on declared variable size? I use C++ Builder XE3.

Comment: Your title asks about C, but the question is tagged C++. Which language are you asking about?

Comment: No, C doesn't specify any such limit. Neither does C++.

Comment: Just keep in mind the stack isn't *that* big usually. Maybe around a megabyte most of the time.

Comment: C *permits* an implementation to impose limits on the sizes of objects. A hosted C implementation must support at least one object of at least 65535 bytes; that doesn't mean any particular object can be that big. I don't know what the corresponding rules are for C++.

Comment: If you're having "weird execution" you might want to ask about that instead, and provide a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Having a (non-static) local array of 100000 bytes is in itself not a problem. If you have *ten* of those (or some that are bigger) then there might be problems. But the answer to *this* question is that there is no such upper limit.

Comment: @chris His variable only requires a 100KB.

Comment: @KeithThompson The rules are the same in C++, except that C++ doesn't require any actual minimum limits.  (On the other hand, it "recommends" supporting a size of at least 262144.  But I'd be very surprised if any compiler actually limits anything other than by the resources available to it.)

Comment: The solution isn't new operator but `vector<char> MyVar(100000);`

Comment: @JamesKanze: In other words, the rules are different. Many operating systems impose much smaller limits on stack size than on total data size; that might out might not be relevant, depending on the OP's actual code.

Comment: @JamesKanze: it may only take 100KB (more accurately ~97.6KB), but maybe he already has other things on the call stack that cause this particular array to overflow the stack.

Comment: @KeithThompson The rules are clearly different; in practice, however, I expect most compilers will implement them the same (with the only limits being those imposed by resource limits).

Answer (score 2):

The expression `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` is an
absolute upper limit, on modern machines, `size_t` is often 64
bits, but even in the 32 bit world, it is 32 bits.  The compiler
or the runtime may impose additional limits; under Windows, for
example, the stack size is extremely limited, so you may get
runtime errors if you allocate too much on the stack.  And I've
managed to get "out of memory" from the compiler (g++) with
tables that were too bit.  (That was machine generated code, and
the tables had initializers, so the compiler had to save them.)

Still, I would not expect 100000 to cause any problems on any
modern machine, even on the stack.  I'd be very surprised if
that was your problem.  There are still memory restrictions, but
they are measured in MegaBytes.

Comment: This helps. When I searched for numeric_limits in the XE3 help, I ended up in the Help section for Dinkumware. I should have explained that I am actually working with complex variables. XE3 uses a complex math library from Dinkumware and I'll bet the problem is related to that library. At least I have a place to start digging. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a static object and it's size is too big for stack. Therefore, you should allocate it dynamically to put it on heap:

```
char *MyVar = new char[100000];
...
delete[] MyVar;
```

or use smart pointer:

```
#include <memory>
std::unique_ptr<char> MyVar(new char[100000]);
```